# Unable to run Protractor tests with chrome browser

Tags: protractor, chrome-web-driver

Getting the following error message. Missing anything?

```
[19:53:22] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[19:53:22] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[19:53:24 INFO(qe-reporter.js:71)] Executed 0 of 0 specs, SUCCESS: 0, FAILED: 0, PENDING: 0, SKIPPED: 0, Duration: 0 sec.
[19:53:24] E/launcher - unknown error: missing or invalid 'width' or 'height'
```

Comment: Could you post your protractor config? Especially the section where you initialize reporters. Thanks.

Comment: Yes looks like a problem in conf file. add the complete conf file.

Comment: "missing or invalid 'width' or 'height'" 
Please post the code where you declare width and height